# Pyqt: Creating a tab in QtDesigner

Tags: pyqt4, qt-designer, qtabwidget

So I have the following problem. I have a MainWindow which contains a Tabwidget. In my main interface, I want to access the widgets in each Tab-page in the following manner:

```
self.tab1.MyLineEdit
self.tab2.MyLineEdit
```

et cetera.

So every tab contains MyLineEdit but I want to access the different ones as members of instances of the QWidgetclass Tab. How can I do that in Qtdesigner? Can I somehow create a tab in QtDesigner and then load it into the tabwidget (by self.tabWidget.add() maybe?)? How could I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add tabs through this code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys

def main():
    app     = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabs    = QtGui.QTabWidget()
# Create tabs
    tab1    = QtGui.QWidget()   
    tab2    = QtGui.QWidget()
    tab3    = QtGui.QWidget()
    tab4    = QtGui.QWidget()
    # Resize width and height
    tabs.resize(250, 150)
    # Set layout of first tab
    vBoxlayout  = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    pushButton1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
    pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Settings")
    pushButton3 = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop")
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton1)
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton2)
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton3)
    tab1.setLayout(vBoxlayout)   

    # Add tabs
    tabs.addTab(tab1,"Tab 1")
    tabs.addTab(tab2,"Tab 2")
    tabs.addTab(tab3,"Tab 3")
    tabs.addTab(tab4,"Tab 4") 

    # Set title and show
    tabs.setWindowTitle('PyQt QTabWidget @ pythonspot.com')
    tabs.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```